# Taylor Expansion of Feynman Propagator with regulator masses and gamma matrices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, regularization

I am currently trying to understand a really old paper of *Jackiw and Coleman*: [*"Why dilatation generators do not generate dilatations"*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(71)90153-9).

There, at some point they arrive at the following integral from a Feynman propagator (wth loops) and regulator masses:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{M_f \rightarrow \infty} g^2 M_f Tr \int \frac{d^d k}{(2 \pi)^d} \gamma_5 \frac{1}{{\not}{k} - M_f} \gamma_5 \frac{1}{{\not}{k} - {\not}p - M_f} \frac{1}{{\not}{k} - {\not} q - M_f}
\end{equation}
where ${\not} k, {\not}p $ and ${\not}q$ are the dirac slashed $k_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu},p_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu},q_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu}$ momenta.

They argue that the integral is convergent and my first question is how can I see it?

I only fully understand the DR regularization way and never actually seen regularization via auxilliary fields and masses. From what I can see the integral will give a k-order divergence and a $M_f^2$ on the denominator. Is it enough to say that the limit $\lim_{M_f \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k}{M_f^2} =0$ ?

Secondly, they argue that if we expand the integral with respect to $p$ and $q$, the only terms that will survive are of order $p^2$ and $q^2$.

So my question is, what do I expand and how since I have gamma matrices on the denominator. Do I expand around $\not k - \not p$?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's my guess as to what's happening here. I'm not an expert in this so hopefully, someone more knowledgable can correct me. In the paper it is stated that

> For these values of the masses, the integral (3.26) has, for any fixed $p$ and $q$, a
> convergent power series expansion in $p$ and $q$ for sufficiently large regulator mass.

I am reading this as "the power series converges in $p$ and $q$, but we haven't said anything about the loop momentum integral". So apart from worrying about the divergence arising from the loop momentum $k$, the authors want to make sure that the power series expansion in the external momenta is also well-defined.

The type of regularization that they are using is called [Pauli-Villars regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli%E2%80%93Villars_regularization). Each one of the integrals is still divergent but taking differences between integrals of different masses can parametrize the divergence in terms of the fictitious regulator mass $M_f$. This is achieved by the following replacement of the propagator

$$\frac{1}{p^2+i \epsilon} \rightarrow\frac{1}{p^2+i \epsilon}- \frac{1}{p^2+M_f^2+i \epsilon}.$$

Before we can show why the integral is divergent, let's first address the gamma matrices in the denominator. When one performs fermion loops, it is standard to use the identity:

$$\frac{1}{\not k -m}=\frac{\not k +m}{k^2 -m^2}, \tag{1} $$

since $(\not k-m)(\not k+ m) = k^2 -m^2$. After such a manipulation, the integral becomes

\begin{equation}
\lim_{M_f \rightarrow \infty} g^2 M_f Tr \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \gamma_5 \frac{{\not}{k} + M_f}{k^2 - M_f^2} \gamma_5 \frac{{\not}{k} - {\not}p + M_f}{(k-p)^2 - M_f^2} \frac{{\not}{k} - {\not} q + M_f}{(k-q)^2 - M_f^2}.
\end{equation}

After performing the trace, we can see that the highest order term will look something like $$\sim \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{k^2}{(k^2- \Delta)^3}\sim \int \frac{k^5}{k^6} \rightarrow \infty,$$ where $\Delta$ is some algebraic combination of the regulator masses, Feynman parameters *etc*... The divergence is logarithmic, not linear since [the trace of an odd number of $\gamma$ matrices is always $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities) in $4$ dimensions. This doesn't change the main message.

The point is that the loop momentum integral diverges, as it should in a QFT. This is why the authors compute the quantities $A(p,q)$, which are the regularized versions of this integral. The convergence they are referring to in that paragraph most likely has to do with a convergence in the sense of justifying their use of Taylor series.

Finally, to address the possibility of performing a Taylor series, I hope the identity (1) answers this question.